# How can I use a program that requires the local console, remotely?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I have a customized program that I need to run remotely (in order to use the computing power of my server). I have run into a problem in which this program doesn't seem to work when it isn't using the local console in Windows Server 2008. I found this out after trying to use it under RemoteApp. The developer of the program isn't willing to try to figure out how to fix it at all (note: it is a technical issue, not a licensing issue).

So my question is, is there any way to handle this or trick the program into thinking it is being used locally? I am willing to sacrifice the "nice" features of RemoteApp and am even willing to go so far as to say I will only have one person logged in at a time. The only requirement is I need to be remote and I can't use VNC.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you just use Windows RDC?

Comment: @bobert5064 When I use Windows RDC it logs me into a non-local session (not sure of the proper terminology) and causes the program to not work.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I hadn't thought of that not being considered a local session, sorry. Since the application is customized, do you have the source code? I don't have a lot of experience in this area, but have you tried to SSH into the machine and run it from there?

Comment: May I ask why VNC is not an option?

Comment: @Zoredache Blocked on the network and I don't have the authority to do anything about it. :(

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this in the question, the program works on Win XP RDP, but not on Server 2k8 RDP.

Comment: @Zoredache That actually looks like it worked! I had tried "-console", but I guess that didn't do what I thought it would. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good, I have moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [/admin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947723) switch with connecting via RDP from a recent RDP client..  It connects actually lets you view the console on Windows 2003 machines.